# recall multiple ROS nodes in one main cpp ROS node

Tags: ros, uav

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm using ROS indigo to fly my Erle Copter,
I want to ask you about ROS nodes,

I have several ROS nodes:
one of these nodes will take reading from one of the sensor and do some calculations, and based on the sensor readings the Copter (UAV) will know its direction.

My question is, if I want to run the ROS node that is responsible of sensor readings after reaching one of the waypoints, how can I call that ROS node so it works only once the UAV reaches the waypoint and move?
and then move to the second waypoint and run the same node again

so recalling ROS node at specific time, can it be achieved  and how?

I hope that you can understand my question since I didn't find what I want in the tutorial, all what I found is how to publish and subscribe in another one, but its not explained how to run a ROS nodes inside another ROS node (main one)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244374/recall-multiple-ros-nodes-in-one-main-cpp-ros-node/) by [Omarzamany](https://answers.ros.org/users/26677/omarzamany/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understood your question, it seems to me that you are looking to this problem from the wrong perspective, you can solve it even with the use of simple topics and services without having to use Actionlib (which is a bit more powerful and complicated).

Have you asked yourself how does a mobile robot navigates or plans a path? (if not, please search for it). It is not difficult, just create a structured architecture where your nodes communicate with each-other (publish/subscribe pattern), where there must be a node that plans your path and a node that takes care of the odometry (position), so, the node that senses the location (odometry) must be publishing the position all the time. In the path planner node, use an if statement inside the listener subscribed to the topic that is publishing the odometry (odom_pose) to make sure that you will generate the new goal only when odom_pose is close enough to the previous goal_pose.

A better question could be more helpful.

---

Originally posted by [pablocesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20992/pablocesar/) with karma: 252 on 2016-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not really sure what you want, but I think you should have a look at actions. [Actionlib](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib)  This allows a node to request another node to solve a task or run an algorithm. In your case one node could tell another one which waypoint was reached and that the node should now start to compute and publish the estimated pose.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-09-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1